# Positive set theory and the "co-Russell" set

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, foundations

*This is a more focused version of a question which was [asked at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2431146/28111) a couple years ago, but is still unanswered there. That question asks about a broad range of theories, whereas this version focuses on a single one.*

Let $S=\{x: x\in x\}$ be the "dual" to Russell's paradoxical set $R$, and consider the question "Is $S\in S$?" If we try to work purely "naively" there does not seem to be an immediate argument one way or the other (dually to the situation for $R$). However, in light of Lob's theorem it's a bit premature to leap to the conclusion that there actually **are** no such arguments.

So it remains plausible that there is a "reasonable" set theory in which the question "Is $S\in S$?" is decided in a nontrivial way. Note that the nontriviality requirement rules out both $\mathsf{ZF}$- and $\mathsf{NF}$-style set theories: the former prove $S=\emptyset$, while the latter prove that $S$ is not a set in the first place.

The most appealing candidate to me appears to be [$\mathsf{GPK}_\infty^+$](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/settheory-alternative/#SystGPKiOlivEsse). This theory proves that $S$ is a set and is nonempty. It also (in my opinion) has a very attractive intuition behind it, as well as an interesting model theory. So my question is:

> Does $\mathsf{GPK}_\infty^+$ decide whether $S\in S$?

Comment: Could you say a bit more how NF proves that $S$ is not a set? (Or did you just mean that it doesn’t obviously prove it *is* a set?)

Comment: @EmilJeřábek $\mathsf{NF}$ proves that the complement of a set is a set, so if $S$ were a set $R$ would be as well.

Comment: Ah, of course! Thank you.

Comment: there are ZF style theories which indeed can decide on that, take ZF with Ur-elements, now if we restrict the non-well founded parts of those theories to just the Quine atoms, and work with models in which there is a set of all quine atoms, then clearly the question is also trivially decidable?

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar I would still call that a trivial solution (although you're right, it's a different trivial solution to the one I stated). I'm really interested in $\mathsf{GPK}_\infty^+$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I've put the answer to the MSE version of this question that you've linked in the head post. A pure formula means just a positive formula (i.e. bounded universal quantifiers are not allowed). According to that answer the solution is simply found as: $$\exists A \forall y (y \in A \iff y \in y \lor y=A)$$.

Comment: How about set theories with [anti-foundation](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nonwellfounded-set-theory/#2.3)? You'd certainly get $S \neq \emptyset$ in those, but I do not see off the top of my head what status $S \not\in S$ gets.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I'm also interested in those, but that would be more appropriate for the MSE version of this question (and I mentioned them there); I decided to focus on $\mathsf{GPK}_\infty^+$ here partly to keep the question more concrete and also because I've gradually come to like that theory in particular. I've edited to clarify this point.

Comment: $\mathsf{GPK}^{+}_{\infty}$ looks interesting indeed, especially to a topologically minded person like me.

Comment: Minor note: There seems to be a typo in the SEP article for the axiom schema of closure (the variable $y$ is not captured by its quantifier).

Comment: @AndrejBauer Re: antifoundation, over something $\mathsf{ZF}$-flavored Aczel's and Boffa's axioms each make $S$ a proper class. The only $\mathsf{ZF}$-flavored versions I'm aware of which make $S$ a nonempty set are fairly artificial, like "There is a Quine atom" + "There is a set of all Quine atoms."

Comment: @NoahSchweber, as regards your last comment, $ZFCU $ + *hereditary size axiom* do indeed prove $S \not \in S$. I personally don't think this theory is artificial. The hereditary size axiom can prove infinity by itself (this axiom is: for every set there is a set of all sets hereditarily smaller than it), this axiom is a non-trivial theorem of ZF, and its not directly related to the self membership problem, you can build hierarchies using this function. This works as long as *all* self membered sets in the theory are hereditarily smaller than some set (i.e., not necessarily quine atoms)

Comment: What’s this about Lob’s Theorem?

Comment: @MonroeEskew Probably https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2135587/variant-of-g%C3%B6del-sentence/2135649.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar Artificiality is subjective, but I do think that theory is artificial. I don't see any motivation for your hereditary size axiom; merely being a nontrivial theorem of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ isn't sufficient for me. Regardless, this question is again specifically about $\mathsf{GPK}_\infty^+$.

Comment: @MonroeEskew The point is that "This statement is unprovable"/"This statement is provable" may at first glance look parallel to $R$/$S$; Lob's theorem then vaguely suggests that the self-membership question for $S$ might not be undetermined. It's purely motivational, feel free to ignore it.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, a non-trivial theorem of ZF. (not just ZFC). I think the hereditary size axiom *is* quite natural!! But adding the restriction of self membered sets to be hereditarily of a size below some specific set size is what's artificial. I agree.

Comment: Well the question had been there for two years. Obviously no one knows the answer!?

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar "Well the question had been there for two years. Obviously no one knows the answer!?" Nobody on *MSE* knew the answer *two years ago*. That doesn't mean that nobody on *MO* knows the answer *now*.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, it looks hard. But as you said possibly someone knows the answer now. Usually in those theories (having big sets) its the *small* sets that really count, as it is the case with NF, we always at the end concentrate on ZF like sets that gives most of the power for the theories, and features of the big sets remains a mystery most of the times because we don't have much control over them, I think the matter is the same with positive set theory. The concentration is on hereditary isolated sets.

Comment: Just out of curiosity : in either case, would S have a non-null proper subset?

Comment: @WalterBruceSinclair This is equivalent to $S$ having at least two elements. The answer is yes; besides the universal set, one way of generating elements of $S$ is as follows. For each set $x$ let $C(x)=\{y: x=y\vee x\in y\}$ be the "cone above $x$." This exists by positive comprehension, and since $x\in C(x)$ we have $C(x)\in C(x)$ and so $C(x)\in S$. So this lets us generate lots of elements of $S$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer has been superseded by a more general argument (based on a result of Cantini's) that I have posted as [an answer to Noah's original MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4515237/228583). In particular, a fairly weak fragment of $\mathsf{GPK}$ is enough to entail that $S \in S$.

---

I will show that $\mathsf{GPK}_\infty^+$ is consistent with $S \in S$, under the assumption of a weakly compact cardinal. Specifically, I'll show that the 'standard models' of $\mathsf{GPK}_\infty^+$ (which require weakly compact cardinals) satisfy $S \in S$. I've made very little progress with proving anything from $\mathsf{GPK}_\infty^+$ directly, although this is probably my failing.

The main idea of the argument is very simple: Show that these models satisfy that for every set $X$, there exists a set $Y$ satisfying $Y = X \cup \{Y\}$. You then note that $S$ must be a fixed point of this operation, so it must be the case that $S \in S$.

For the sake of completeness, I will give the construction of a model of $\mathsf{GPK}_\infty^+$ in a way that should feel familiar to classical set theorists. I'm also doing this because I couldn't find a presentation of this construction that I liked online, although I did use the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy article [Alternative Axiomatic Set Theories](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/settheory-alternative/) to get the general idea.

---

**Construction**

Recall that a *forest* is a partially ordered set in which the set of predecessors of any element is well-ordered. A *tree* is a forest with a unique minimal element. I'll use the word *path* to refer to a downwards-closed, linearly ordered set. (I can't remember if there's a standard term for this.) The *height* of a path is its order type as an ordinal. The *height* of a node $x \in T$ is the height of the path $\{ y \in T : y < x\}$. To make the presentation more uniform between successor and limit stages, we'll refer to paths as having *children*, rather than just nodes. A node $x$ is the child of a path $A$ if $\{ y \in T : y < x\} = A$. A path $A$ is the *parent* of a node $x$ if $x$ is the child of $A$. Finally, a *branch* is a path of maximal height. (The forest we will construct will not have any dead paths that are shorter than the forest itself.)

We will build a forest (although really it's just a tree and an isolated branch corresponding to the empty set) whose nodes of height $\alpha$ are labeled with sets of paths of height $\alpha$. (Note that this isn't circular, because the paths of height $\alpha$ do not contain nodes of height $\alpha$.) Every set of paths of height $\alpha$ will be attached to precisely one node of height $\alpha$. We will use the convention that lowercase letters refer to sets of paths and that uppercase letters refer to paths of sets.

At stage $0$, there is a unique path of length $0$, the empty path $\Lambda$, and there are  two sets of such paths, the empty set and the singleton $\{\Lambda\}$, so these are the roots of the two trees in our forest.

At non-zero stage $\alpha$, given the forest built up to height $\alpha$, we add each set $x$ of paths of length $\alpha$ as a node. The parent of the node $x$ is the unique path $A$ with the property that for any node $y \in A$,

- for every $B \in x$, there exists a $C \in y$ such that $B$ extends $C$ and
- for every $C \in y$, there exists a $B \in x$ such that $B$ extends $C$.

It is not hard to show by induction that this is well defined.

Now we build this forest up to a height $\kappa$, where $\kappa$ is a weakly compact cardinal. The elements of the model are the branches of the forest, and the element of relation is defined by $A \in B$ iff for every $\alpha < \kappa$, $A \upharpoonright \alpha \in B(\alpha)$. This structure is typically referred to as the *$\kappa$-hyperuniverse*, but I'll just call it $M$.

---

**Argument**

I claim that $M$ satisfies the following:

> For every $X \in M$, there exists $Y \in M$ such that $Z \in Y$ if and only if either $Z \in X$ or $Z = Y$.

It's easy to see how this resolves the status of $S \in S$. Let $S' = S \cup \{S'\}$. Clearly by construction, $S' \supseteq S$ and $S' \in S'$. Therefore we have $S' \in S$, but this implies that $S \supseteq S'$, so $S = S'$ and $S \in S$. I think the most reasonable approach to resolving your question would be to prove this claim directly from $\mathsf{GPK}_\infty^+$, but I can't even show that $\mathsf{GPK}_\infty^+$ entails the existence of a Quine atom. (Or that any two Quine atoms are equal, for that matter.) Someone probably knows how to do this, though, and I'd be interested to see it.

*Proof of claim.* To prove this, consider the path corresponding to $X$. Let $Y$ be the $\kappa$-indexed sequence of nodes on the forest defined inductively by $Y(\alpha) = X(\alpha) \cup \{ Y \upharpoonright \alpha\}$ for each $\alpha < \kappa$. We need to show that this is well defined.

- For $\alpha = 0$, $Y \upharpoonright 0 = \Lambda$, so $Y(0) = X(0) \cup \{\Lambda\}$.
- For a non-zero $\alpha$, assuming we've shown that $Y \upharpoonright \alpha$ is actually a path on the forest, we immediately get that $Y(\alpha) = X(\alpha) \cup \{ Y \upharpoonright \alpha\}$ is a node of height $\alpha$ in the forest. We just need to show  that $Y(\alpha)$'s parent is $Y\upharpoonright \alpha$. Fix a node $Y(\beta) \in Y \upharpoonright \alpha$ (for some $\beta < \alpha$). For any $A \in Y(\alpha)$, either $A \in X(\alpha)$ or $A = Y\upharpoonright \alpha$. In the first case, by the fact that $X\upharpoonright \alpha$ is a path, there must exist a $B \in X(\alpha)$ such that $A$ extends $B$. In the second case,  $Y \upharpoonright \beta \in Y(\beta)$ and is extended by $Y\upharpoonright \alpha$ (by the induction hypothesis). Essentially the same argument gives that for any $B \in Y(\beta)$, there is an $A \in Y(\alpha)$ extending $B$.

Therefore $Y$ is a branch of the forest and corresponds to an element of $M$. $Y$ is clearly a superset of $X$ and clearly contains $Y$ as an element. We need to show that $Y = X \cup \{Y\}$.

Suppose that $Z \in Y$. For each $\alpha < \kappa$, we get that either $Z \upharpoonright \alpha = Y \upharpoonright \alpha$ or $Z \upharpoonright \alpha \in X(\alpha)$. Because of the way forests/trees work, if there is an $\alpha$ such that $Z \upharpoonright \alpha \neq Y \upharpoonright \alpha$, then this must also be true for any $\beta \in (\alpha,\kappa)$. Therefore, if $Z \neq Y$, then for some $\alpha < \kappa$, we have that $Z \upharpoonright \beta \in X(\beta)$ for all $\beta \in (\alpha,\kappa)$. It's not hard to show that the same must be true for any $\beta <\kappa$, so we have that $Z \in X$, proving the claim.

Comment: Very nice, I like this a lot! I'll accept it once I've had a chance to read it in detail and convince myself it works (granted it doesn't answer the full question, but based on how long this has been open I think this is a good stopping point for it).